# Cutting and reassembling squares

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Is there a general way to cut a square into polygonal pieces so that the pieces can be assembled into n equally sized squares for each n? For example, 2 and 4 and n=k^2 is obvious (2 by the diagonals and the n=k^2 by k rows and k columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a systematic method.  I am not good at drawing diagrams online so please draw them for yourself - I hope my instructions are clear.

Given a square $ABCD$ of side length $\sqrt n$, we want to cut it up and arrange the pieces into $n$ unit squares.  Let $k=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ be the largest integer not greater than $\sqrt n$.  Locate $F$ on $CD$ such that
$$DF=\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{k^2}-n}\ .$$
Draw $AF$, and find $E$ on $AF$ such that $BE\perp AF$.

Now cut off the triangle $ADF$ and attach the side $AD$ to $BC$, thus forming a parallelogram with altitude $BE$.  You can check that the length of $BE$ is $k$, that is, it is an integer, so this parallelogram can be cut into parallelograms of altitude $1$; these can then be placed side by side to make one long parallelogram of altitude $1$.

Then cut a bit off one side and transfer it to the opposite side to form an $n\times1$ rectangle.  It is then easy to cut this into $n$ unit squares.

Sorry if this is confusing but if you draw the diagrams I think you will find it's not too hard to follow.

**Comments**.

- It is possible that $DF=0$, that is, $F=D$.  This is not a problem.
- You can in fact take other integer values for $k$.  I'm not sure if all of them work.

Answer (score 3):

By the [Bolyai-Gerwien Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace%E2%80%93Bolyai%E2%80%93Gerwien_theorem) if $A$ and $B$ are polygonal regions of equal area, then $A$ can be decomposed into a finite number of polygonal pieces which can be reassembled to form $B$.  So of $A$ is our square, divide it into $n$ rectangles of equal area in the obvious way. Then these rectangles can be divided into polygonal pieces which can be reassembled to make our $n$ squares.

**Remark:** Decomposing a rectangle into polygonal pieces that can be reassembled into a square is relatively simple. If the length is much greater than the width, cut into congruent rectangles and stack the pieces until you have a rectangle which is no worse than $1\times 4$. Then by drawing a single line one can decompose that rectangle into pieces that can be reassembled to make a square. Please [see this, Figure 9.1.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=tRdoIhHh3moC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=decomposing+a+rectangle+to+make+a+square+bolyai&source=bl&ots=ByK94jlpUw&sig=QtFpuIppeQMkpaSK6hrncqx-E0o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nJ3VVPatCtO6ogTm8YGoDw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=decomposing%20a%20rectangle%20to%20make%20a%20square%20bolyai&f=false)

Comment: Is this proof constructive? I am reading the wiki article but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Yes, it is completely constructive. One can give a straightedge and compass recipe. If the rectangle has base much greater than the height, we can fix that by bisecting and stacking enough times. After that it is one step. I wish I could draw the picture.

Comment: Here is [another picture](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ywKyQz7_4-MC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=cutting+a+rectangle+and+reassembling+the+pieces+bolyai&source=bl&ots=GOQDaGanWP&sig=SEAZQefuB5SZ2ki9gSd8xKEiTSk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7KHVVIC5EdTcoATZ2YLwAQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=cutting%20a%20rectangle%20and%20reassembling%20the%20pieces%20bolyai&f=false) of the last step, page 63.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we can "$n$-cut" a square if we can cut a square into polygonal pieces that can be assembled into $n$ equally sized squares. Note that if you can $a$-cut a square and also $b$-cut a square, then you can $ab$-cut a square (just $b$-cut each of the $a$ smaller squares, or vice versa). Therefore it suffices to $p$-cut a square for every prime $p$.

I'm guessing this is possible. $3$-cutting a square is a [classical problem](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/161493/files/Square_Trisection) (see especially page $4$). I also found a [picture](http://chestofbooks.com/crafts/children/Paper-Folding/images/III-Squares-And-Rectangles-44.jpg) $5$-cutting a square. I imagine that these diagonal-lattice cutting strategies can be generalized quite substantially, perhaps to all primes $p$.

Comment: The 3 and 5 cases were very illuminating, thanks. I quite like that article. Also, do we know those are the least number of pieces needed? They seem like it, but I'm not sure.